# Testing "https:..." URLs through Selenium gives Secure Connection Error in FireFox 50 and 52

Tags: security, firefox, selenium-webdriver, connection

I am sure many of us are using Selenium to test applications with URL starting with https://....
I am facing this issue in my client network  local and Jumpboxes, whenever  I do a driver.get(“https://....”) to these URLs.

URLs starting with http://.... works fine.

I am using gecko 0.14, selenium 3.3.1 standalone server and Mozilla 50.1.0. Also checked with gecko 0.15.

Went through the suggestions over net and tried out the following workarounds :

•   Creating new profile and setting capabilities and other properties. This helps manually , but through selenium the same issue persists.
•   Adding Exception in Browser for new profile as well as default profile.
•   Downloaded Mozilla 52.0 and tried the same.

None of them helped me out.

Questions :

Is this a proxy issue.
Can this be resolved.

Issue going on for a while. Please let us know if anything helped you out to resolve this.

Thanks,
Arpan

Comment: Did solution work ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new FireFox profile say "myProfile".

```
ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni()                
FirefoxProfile ffProfile= prof.getProfile ("myProfile")
```

Now we need to set "`setAcceptUntrustedCertificates`" and "`setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer`" properties in the FireFox profile.

```
ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true) 
ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false)
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver (ffProfile)
```

"`setAcceptUntrustedCertificates`" and "`setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer`" are capabilities to handle the certificate errors in web browsers.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, Thanks for the reply...actually i have tried this .. but did not help...

Comment: But i have solved the issue now... i have upgraded my selenium 3.3.1 to 3.4 and now its actually reading my new profile...thus solving the issue